# Is it possible to use GIT and TFS source control together

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

We are currently using VS 2015 with TFS bases source control but are considering moving to Microsoft GIT. Is it possible to use the two together so that we can evaluate and compare. Looking at Source Control plug in section in VS options it implies that you can only use one or the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good timing, it's in the post with TFS2015 Update 1 which is currently in Release Candidate.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/tfs2015-update1-vs.aspx

Git and TFVC in the same project

Team Foundation Server now supports adding Git repositories to Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) Team Projects or adding TFVC repositories to Git team projects. This makes it easier to adopt a new version control system while keeping all your current team project data. Team members will need to run Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 to easily switch between TFVC and Git in the same team project.

Comment: that link now redirects to VS2017 release notes

Comment: You'd need to get TFS 2015 Update 4 now or move to TFS 2017/VSTS. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2015-update4-vs